# error: Void Value not ignored as it ought to be, C programming

Tags: c

I just have a really quick question to ask of all of you. I keep having the problem in my C code, where it says

```
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

The problem where my code is happening is in the call statement in order for the function to run

```
m = myMax1(a,len,m);
```

and the function that is void where this is coming from is as below:

```
void myMax1( int *arr, int *max, int n )
{
     max = arr[0];
     for(n = 0; n < max; n++)
     {
         if(arr[n]>max)
         {
             max = arr[n];
         }
     }
}
```

If you have any solutions, please let me know! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're assigning the return of function myMax1 to m, but this function doesn't return anything.

Comment: `max = arr[0]`, `n < max`, `arr[n]>max`, `max = arr[n]` - none of these expressions make sense. And what was the point of passing `n` from outside if inside the function the passed value is destroyed by `n = 0` anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning anything but you're assigning the return value to a variable `m`. If you're calling it just for side effects, don't assing the return value to anything.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a simple mistake on my part. This fixed it

Answer (score 0):

When a function returns `void`, you cannot use:

```
m = myMax1(a,len,m);
```

You can use:

```
myMax1(a,len,m);
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped tremendously!